# how do I output git diff to a text file using python

Tags: python, git, git-diff

I am trying to make a command for git to directly email the diff,

what I have thought is to get the diff to a text file to email,

but not sure why

```
pr = subprocess.Popen( "git diff HEAD^ HEAD" , cwd = os.path.dirname( os.getcwd() ), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
(out, error) = pr.communicate()
print "Error : " + str(error) 
print "out : " + str(out)
```

gives error saying

```
Error : error: Could not access 'HEAD^'

out :
```

whereas I want diff in out variable to email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not issuing the command in correct folder, where git is initialized.

Your actual problem is, that `os.path.dirname` command is striping out the folder from the command `os.getcwd` and you are actually running the command in parent folder. If you get rid of `os.path.dirname` and just use `os.getcwd` your code should work.

Comment: resized if I don't do `cwd = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())`  and just `cwd = os.getcwd()` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes to be made in the code to work .
Changes are git commands inside Popen and working directory.
After making the changes the code can be as given below which will work without any error

```
pr = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', 'HEAD~1' ,'HEAD'] , cwd = os.getcwd(), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
(out, error) = pr.communicate()
print "Error : " + str(error) 
print "out : " + str(out)
```